# When styling XML with CSS, how to refer to tag names that contain periods or colons?

Tags: css, xml, css-selectors

I'm styling an XML document that contains tags like `<a.b></a.b>` or `<b:c></b:c>`. Now of course if I write CSS rules like

```
a.b {
} 

b:c {
}
```

It won't work because these characters will be interpreted as classes and pseudo-classes, respectively. Is there a way to refer to these tag names with CSS? (I don't want to use [XSL](http://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/)...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned, to refer to an element with a `.` in its tag name you can simply escape it:

```
a\.b
```

But the same *can't* be said for a `b:c` element, because `:` has a special meaning in XML, as a namespace separator. This means that the element you have is actually a `c` element in the `b` [namespace](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names), not an element called `b:c`.<sup>1</sup>

That said, there are two correct ways to select that element. First, since as I mentioned the element is actually called `c` and not `b:c`, you can simply use:

```
c
```

The second way, in case of namespace collisions, is to first declare the `b` namespace in the beginning of your stylesheet using [`@namespace`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-namespace) corresponding to the one in your XML document (there should be an `xmlns:b` namespace reference somewhere in your document, otherwise it won't be valid):

```css
/* Whichever URL corresponds to xmlns:b in your XML document */
@namespace b 'http://ns.example.com/b';
```

Then use a [namespace prefix](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#typenmsp) to select the element:

```
b|c
```

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Remember that we're talking about XML here, not HTML or any arbitrary markup language where `:` holds no special meaning.</sub>