# ruby how to parse this xml data that contains <g:?

Tags: ruby, xml, parsing

I have xml data like below-

```
                      <rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" version="2.0">
```

rgrf
frrv

Comment: Is this not the entire document? I think there should be a `xmlns:g="something"` attribute somewhere to establish g as a namespace. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15849357/when-styling-xml-with-css-how-to-refer-to-tag-names-that-contain-periods-or-col#15849617 and https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/

Comment: Sorry, I have updated my csv.

Comment: I have updated only portion of it. It contains man <item> tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The g is a namespace and needs a namespace declaration as outlined on https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/

```
xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0"
```

You should be able to select the link with the CSS query `g|image_link` and change the link like this.

```
def self.process_xml_data(xml_str)
  puts "process_xml_data"
  xml_doc  = Nokogiri::XML(xml_str)
  image_link_tag = xml_doc.at_css "g|image_link"
  image_link_tag.content = "new_link"
end
```

Comment: Sorry, I have updated my csv. Could you please check it once?

Comment: I think I can't use this line doc = File.open("source.xml") { |f| Nokogiri::XML(f) } because my csv is 1.5 GB long.

Comment: I have updated only portion of it. It contains man <item> tags.